# PowerShell Word 2007/2010/2013 Add a Caption to Table and Move Table 3 Tabs to Right

Tags: powershell, ms-word

PowerShell V2
Word 2007/2010/2013

I have created a test script the inserts a Word table and populates it with no issues.

There are two more things I would like to do:

Add a caption above the table that says "Table x Citrix Services"
Move the table to the right three tab stops.

Sample document can be found at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43555945/StackOverflowSample.docx

Here is my test code:

```
$wdSeekPrimaryFooter = 4
$wdAlignPageNumberRight = 2
$wdStory = 6
$wdMove = 0
$wdSeekMainDocument = 0
$wdColorGray15 = 14277081
$wdCaptionPositionAbove = 0

$Word = New-Object -comobject "Word.Application"
$Word.Visible = $True
$word.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks()
$BuildingBlocks=$word.Templates | Where {$_.name -eq "Built-In Building Blocks.dotx"}
$part=$BuildingBlocks.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("Motion")

$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection

$part.Insert($selection.Range,$True) | out-null
$selection.InsertNewPage()

#table of contents
$toc=$BuildingBlocks.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("Automatic Table 2")
$toc.insert($selection.Range,$True) | out-null

#set the footer
[string]$footertext="Report created by Webster"

#get the footer
$doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.view.SeekView=$wdSeekPrimaryFooter
#get the footer and format font
$footers=$doc.Sections.Last.Footers
foreach ($footer in $footers) 
{
    if ($footer.exists) 
    {
        $footer.range.Font.name="Calibri"
        $footer.range.Font.size=8
        $footer.range.Font.Italic=$True
        $footer.range.Font.Bold=$True
    }
} #end Foreach

$selection.HeaderFooter.Range.Text=$footerText

#add page numbering
$selection.HeaderFooter.PageNumbers.Add($wdAlignPageNumberRight) | Out-Null

#return focus to main document
$doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.view.SeekView=$wdSeekMainDocument

#move to the end of the current document
$selection.EndKey($wdStory,$wdMove) | Out-Null

$services = get-service | where-object {$_.DisplayName -like "*Citrix*"} | sort-object DisplayName

$TableRange = $doc.application.selection.range
$Columns = 2
$Rows = $services.count + 1
$Table = $doc.Tables.Add($TableRange, $Rows, $Columns)
$table.AutoFitBehavior(1)
$table.Style = "Table Grid"
$table.Borders.InsideLineStyle = 1
$table.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 1
$xRow = 1
$Table.Cell($xRow,1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = $wdColorGray15
$Table.Cell($xRow,1).Range.Font.Bold = $True
$Table.Cell($xRow,1).Range.Text = "Display Name"
$Table.Cell($xRow,2).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = $wdColorGray15
$Table.Cell($xRow,2).Range.Font.Bold = $True
$Table.Cell($xRow,2).Range.Text = "Status"
ForEach($Service in $Services)
{
    $xRow++
    $Table.Cell($xRow,1).Range.Text = $Service.DisplayName
    $Table.Cell($xRow,2).Range.Text = $Service.Status
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$Selection.InsertCaption(-2, "Citrix Services")` to create a table title by placing that code above your foreach loop that builds the rows.
The first argument is the caption type; -2 is *Table* other built in labels accessible by negative integers are figure and equation.

Use rows.setleftindent() to indent the table to your desired position.  The first argument is the indent distance the second defines the rulerstyle.
Move your autofitbehavior instance after the indent to ensure the table autofits correctly.

Add the following lines to your code after the foreach loop that builds the table rows.

```
$Table.Rows.SetLeftIndent(200,1)
$table.AutoFitBehavior(1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH this worked like a charm.  For my document I had to change SetLeftIndent(200,1) to SetLeftIndent(75,1).  In the article I wrote, I said I would give credit to the person who showed me how to do these items.  May I credit you in the article I am writing for the update to my script?  Original article is here: http://carlwebster.com/documenting-a-citrix-xenapp-6-5-farm-with-microsoft-powershell-and-word-version-3/

Comment: Great!  I'm glad it helped and sure you may credit me if you'd like.  
If I answered your question would you also mark this as an answer here or maybe just "thumb-up" the answer as helpful?